# Galois group of some degree-72-extension over $\mathbb{Q}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $L_0$ be the splitting field of $f=x^4 + 2x + 2$ over $K=\mathbb{Q}_2$.

We take two distinct roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in L_0$ and set $C = (\alpha_2-\alpha_1)^4$, and set $L = L_0(\sqrt[3]{C})$.

> **Question**: What is the Galois group of the extension $L/K$?

**Observations which I found and that may help**:

- The Galois group of $L_0/K$ is $S_4$ since it can be shown that the resolvent cubic of $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and the discriminant of $f$ is no square over $\mathbb{Q}_2$.
- The extension $L/L_0$ is Galois since $L_0$ contains some (and therefore all) primitive third roots of unity. Therefore, $L/L_0$ is cyclic of degree $3$.
- Therefore, the Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ must have $\operatorname{Gal}(L/L_0) = C_3$ as a subgroup and $\operatorname{Gal}(L_0/K) = S_4$ is a quotient of $G$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to continue from here?

Comment: Being irreducible over a field and having nonsquare discriminant does *not* imply a Galois group is a symmetric group.  For example, $x^4 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ (Eisenstein at $2$) with discriminant $-2048$, which is not a square, but its Galois group over $\mathbf Q$ is dihedral of order $8$, not $S_4$.  The mistake you made is having a nonsquare discriminant tells you the Galois group is not in the alternating group on the roots, but there are lots of (transitive) subgroups of $S_n$ not in $A_n$ other than $S_n$ itself.

Comment: It is true that your quartic has Galois group $S_4$ over $\mathbf Q_2$, but not for the reason you gave.  Instead, check the resolvent cubic is $R(x) = x^3 - 8x - 4$, which is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_2$: it is a cubic with no root in $\mathbf Q_2$. A root in $\mathbf Q_2$ would be in $\mathbf Z_2$, so there would be a root mod $2^n$ for all $n$, but $R(x)$ has no root mod $8$. Since your quartic is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_2$ with nonsquare discriminant and its resolvent cubic is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_2$, the Galois group of the quartic over $\mathbf Q_2$ is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Comment: Whoops, yes I meant that the resolvent cubic is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_2$, my bad.